# How to write Render function in SFC?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-render-function

I'm trying to pass a SFC component as a parameter, and then render in somewhere. In my case, It actually is creating a menu based on routes which provide "icon" field.

here is the routes:

```
import { AppRouteRecordRaw } from '../types';
import AddSvgIconVue from "@/components/icons/AddSvgIcon.vue";

const routes: AppRouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/admin',
    meta: {
      hideInMenu: true
    },
    component: () => import("@/pages/admin/index.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'userManagement',
        meta: {
          icon: AddSvgIconVue,
          title: '用户管理'
        },
        component: () => import("@/pages/admin/SubPages/UserManagement/index.vue")
      },
      {
        path: 'userManagement2',
        meta: {
          icon: AddSvgIconVue,
          hideInMenu: false,
          title: '用户'
        },
        component: () => import("@/pages/admin/SubPages/UserManagement/index.vue"),
        
      }
    ]

  },
]

export default routes;
```

And Here is the Menu Component. and the question is I want to know how should I convert the TSX component to SFC correctlly?

[image]

Comment: `<component is`.

Comment: I can not use component, because it needs me pre-load all related components(right here, It gonna be Icons component, so I need define it in "routes" as a string, and Import Icon here, that's not what i want.  apprrciate!)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it would be `<component is="menuItem..."`. If you mean that "icon" is the name of globally registered component then you'd need resolveComponent() before using it, but the same applies to render function. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce, so it could be fixed.